# Extract using regex extractor - Redirect

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to extract some strings.

How do I extract using the regex extractor from the intermediate redirect URL. The issue is regex extractor is not able to match if redirect happened.

I unchecked the Redirect automatically checkbox and it was able to capture regex value, however I don't know to redirect using that variable.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this resolved, by using another HTTP request calling the initial url and used regex to parse data and call the redirect url with another HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a PostProcessor=> Regular Expression Extractor, and select 'URL' under the field to check section.

You will have to add a Reference name for the variable also the regular expression which will help extract it. Further reference this variable in other requests.